# Change Table View Data Source with Button not working?

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

Currently, I have a switch on top of my table view which is supposed to change where the data is coming from. The switch calls this function

```swift
   @objc func controlValueChanged(_sender: BetterSegmentedControl) {
    if _sender.index == 0 {
        //friend feed
        tableView.dataSource = HomeViewController()
        tableView.delegate = HomeViewController()
        tableView.reloadData()
            print("friends")

    }
    else if _sender.index == 1 {
        //school feed
        tableView.dataSource = schoolFeedViewController()
        tableView.delegate = schoolFeedViewController()
        tableView.reloadData()
    print("school")
    }

}
```

When I change the state from index 0 to index 1, the table view seems to switch, albeit no table view shows as the data source is empty. However, when I switch from index 1 to index 0, nothing happens. The console log prints "friends" but no table view shows.

Here is how the code looks like for schoolFeedViewController():

```swift
    class schoolFeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var postList = [Post]()
    var currentSchool: String?
    var currentGrade: String?
    var schoolExists: Bool?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getSchool()
        fetchFeed()
    }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "schoolFeedCell") as! schoolFeedTableViewCell
        let schoolPost = postList[indexPath.row]

        cell.post.text = schoolPost.post_words
        return cell
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the delegate and removing the table view from the second data source but to no avail.

Comment: It looks like you’re creating two new instances of `HomeViewController` every time segment zero is selected, and two new instances of `schoolFeedViewController` every time segment one is selected. Are you sure that’s what you want to do?

Comment: @rob, not really. What I am trying to do is create a table view that can easily switch sources without having to reload everything from scratch. The data is from a databse, and there are two different types of feeds. I want the user to be able to switch the source so that the other data source will continue to be active (the observers will continue listening and the initial data will not have to be reloaded) and present the other data in the view controller when they press the switch. Not really sure if I’m going about this the right way, but I think it’s better than creating two table views.

Comment: @robmayoff do you understand what I am trying to achieve? Is swapping the data source the correct way to go about it, and if so do I need to change my approach?

Comment: Swapping is fine, but you shouldn't be creating new instances every time. You should be creating one instance of each and keeping them around.

Comment: @robmayoff How would I go about creating one instance and keeping it about?

Answer (score 2):

I have your solution

1. Save the State of _sender.index value in one Int Variable 'selectedTab'
2. when `@objc func controlValueChanged(_sender: BetterSegmentedControl) {` is call 
   only reload tha tableview on both index

   ```
    if _sender.index == 0 {
       //friend feed
       tableView.reloadData()
           print("friends")

   }
   else if _sender.index == 1 {
       //school feed
       tableView.reloadData()
   ```

   }
3. Use Switch case for DataSouce Methods like

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   ```
       switch selectedTab {
       case 0:
           return arrFrind.count
       case 1:
           return arrScool.count
       default:
           return 0
       }
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       switch selectedTab {

       case 0:

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell0")!

           return cell

       case 1:

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1")!

           return cell


       default:
           return UITableViewCell()
       }

   }
   ```
4. in switch selectedTab has the value of _sender.index
5. Done Simple

Comment: thanks and please correct my answer if it is useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot about delegate methods like this

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

please provide this code 
also check that your data array is not be empty 
but i recommend you to provide two different prototype cells and switch between them and not to entirely change tableview datasource and delegate

Comment: I don't have numberOfSections in either View Controller and it seems to be working fine individually. Both table views DO use different prototype cells, also. I want the table view to just change where the data is coming from, rather than having two separate view controllers as the tables will be essentially the same in format and having two view controllers rather than one with a tableview with tabs is more cluttered.

Comment: i just don't understand why you don't changing the data and filling tableview with new data instead of changing datasource and delegate. my question is what is advantage of changing datasource and delegate for you ? @RaimKhalil

Comment: There is no advantage. How would I change the data and refill the table view? That is what I am intending to do.

Comment: would I just switch the array being used?

Comment: changing array is good but you should bind that data too
so if your new data is different from older one i recommend you to have 2 different prototype cells and bind appropriate cell depending on your data

Comment: so how would I load up the different cells? Would I have the different feed in a different class, and for the cellforrowat method I call the different cell? How would I switch between these cells, then, when the button is pressed?

Comment: Okay, I got it.  Just called function to get  new data and switched cell count.